# Python TCP Select() not serving browser without termination

Tags: python, sockets, select, tcp, webserver

I'm trying to create a simple TCP server application and have followed https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/ this tutorial and got the same code:

```
import select, socket, sys, queue
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)
tcp_port = int(sys.argv[1])
server.bind(('localhost', tcp_port))
server.listen(5)
inputs = [server]
outputs = []
message_queues = {}
response = """
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: Closed\n
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>This is the body</body>
</html>
"""

while inputs:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
    for s in readable:
        if s is server:
            connection, client_address = s.accept()
            connection.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(connection)
            message_queues[connection] = queue.Queue()
        else:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print('received from: ', s)
            if data:
                message_queues[s].put(str.encode(response))
                if s not in outputs:
                    outputs.append(s)
            else:
                if s in outputs:
                    outputs.remove(s)
                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
                del message_queues[s]

    for s in writable:
        try:
            next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            outputs.remove(s)
        else:
            print('sending to: ', s)
            s.send(next_msg)

    for s in exceptional:
        inputs.remove(s)
        if s in outputs:
            outputs.remove(s)
        s.close()
        del message_queues[s]
```

I then run it in the terminal and when I connect to the server using another python client application, I receive the response as expected. However, if I connect to the server through my browser i.e. localhost:4444, the page hangs on loading and never displays the HTML until I manually terminate the server application. It appears to never reach the code to close() the socket when connected to by a browser. Is there a fundamental difference in the type of connection sent to the server that causes this?

TL;DR:
Created TCP server using python sockets and select(), works with python client, but browser doesn't receive the response until I manually terminate the server

For reference, here is my client code:

```
import socket
import sys

httpRequest = """
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: localhost:4443\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0\r\n
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n\r\n'
"""

server_address = ('localhost', 4442)

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
print('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*server_address), file=sys.stderr)
sock.connect(server_address)
message = httpRequest
outgoing_data = message.encode()
# Send messages on both sockets
print('{}: sending {!r}'.format(sock.getsockname(), outgoing_data), file=sys.stderr)
sock.send(outgoing_data)
# Read responses on both sockets
data = sock.recv(1024)
print('{}: received {!r}'.format(sock.getsockname(), data), file=sys.stderr)
if not data:
    print('closing socket', sock.getsockname(), file=sys.stderr)
    sock.close()
```

Comment: So, you created a TCP server to serve HTTP? I do not understand why you would want to do that. I did create a TCP server once, but I did not try accessing it with a standard client like a browser. Instead, I accessed it using a simple TCP client. Do you have a reason to believe that your server adheres to the HTTP protocol?

Comment: @AmitaIrron this is for part of an assignment in which we must request data from a server via a web browser over TCP. I may be misunderstanding the use of the HTTP protocol - I tested this without using select() and only handling one connection, and my browser displayed my response HTML code correctly, so as far as I know, the response should be correctly read by the browser. It seems that the response never reaches the browser in the select() case, at least until I terminate the server.

Comment: *"I may be misunderstanding the use of the HTTP protocol"* - actually, you don't do anything specific to HTTP in your server which suggests that you don't understand the basic concepts of HTTP. Please read at least the [Wikipedia article about HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) to get a basic understanding of what the server is supposed to do.